# Parsing out IP address and RDNS server from string in perl

Tags: perl, parsing, header, ip

Is there any way perl can take an emails Received header information and take its server and IP address out of the string? Here's an example:

```
Received: from example.web.site.net (example.web.site.net [1.1.1.1])  (using example     filler text (256/256 bits))  (No client certificate requested)  by example.example.com     (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 123456
```

These 2 items would need to go to their respective fields when eventually sent out to a SQL database.

This is using the qpsmtp plugin as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly:

- **example.web.site.net** is the server name; and
- **1.1.1.1** is the IP

The best way to do it is using Regex capture. Perl captures any string that matches a certain expression that is enclosed in a parenthesis. It returns an array when you try to match a string with a certain regex (m//).

Here's my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "Received: from example.web.site.net (example.web.site.net [1.1.1.1])  (using example     filler text (256/256 bits))  (No client certificate requested)  by example.example.com     (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 123456";

my ($server, $ip) = $str =~ m/\((.+)\[(.+?)\]\)/sg;
chop($server);

print "'$server' - '$ip'";
```

Well I used a regex to match this part of the string "*(example.web.site.net [1.1.1.1])*" and I just enclosed the parts of that string that I want to capture with parenthesis. And since I want to get 2 strings, hence the assignment:

```
my ($server, $ip) = $str =~ m/\((.+)\[(.+?)\]\)/sg;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Much thanks! This helped a lot.
This works perfectly when the server is before the IP.
In some cases we receive emails where the IP is before the server, which returns null values.
Would you know of a workaround for that?

Comment: What you could do is modify regex in such a way that it matches the new pattern. Check first if it returns null, and if does, do a regex capture (using your new regex) on the string provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try a regex:

```
my $str = "Received: from example.web.site.net (example.web.site.net [1.1.1.1])  (using example     filler text (256/256 bits))  (No client certificate requested)  by example.example.com     (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 123456";    
$str =~ s/[^\(]*\(([^ ]+) \[([^\]]+)\]\).*/$1|$2/; 

my @parts = split /\|/, $str;
```

`$parts[0]` has the server, `$parts[1]` has the IP